# Parse values between two elements

Tags: javascript, regex

**Input:**

```
var str = 'text {{value1}} text {{value2}}text{{value1}}';
```

**Regex:**

```
var result = str.match(/({{\S+}})+/ig);
```

**Output:**

```
["{{value1}}", "{{value2}}text{{value1}}"]
```

What regex should I use to get the next result:

```
["{{value1}}", "{{value2}}", "{{value1}}"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the regex to be non-greedy:

```
var result = str.match(/({{\S+?}})+/ig);
```

I added a `?` after the `\S+`. This makes the `+` match as few as possible.

Answer (score 2):

<del>You need to escape the curly braces as they are special syntax for specifying [how many repeats to match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)</del>

`/({{\S+?}})+/ig`

Edit: I didn't notice that actually adding the [non-greedy specifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) did the trick.

Comment: That's not the problem at all. They're unambiguous unless they're of the form `{\d+}` or `{(\d+)?,(\d+)?}`. Your non-greedy specifier did the trick.